# How to change color of the dot on the "i" letter in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, path

How can I change the color of the dot part (in this case, the dot is the triangle) on "i" letter with Illustrator?
I have done the Create Outlines but I can only change the I color as a whole.
I'm still noob in Illustrator so I need your help to enlighten me.
Thanks

[image: My Logo]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your text

right click and choose `Release Compound Path` or `Object -> Compound Path -> Release`

[image]

you will then be able to alter the i

[image]

---

If you want to just move the dot of the "i":

[image]

Select all the text with the `Selection tool` <kbd>V</kbd> and right click.

[image]

Right click again and ungroup

[image]

You can then use the `Direct Selection tool` <kbd>A</kbd> and select the shape to alter the points or just click the selection tool again to move it

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it's a Compound Path. With the outlined 'i' selected, use <kbd>Object → Compound Path → Release</kbd> (or just right click on it and select Release Compound Path). The shapes will then be separated and you can change the colors independently.